# Definition of position for List ADT (singly linked list implementation)

Tags: data-structures

`Chapter 2: Basic Abstract Data Types` of the book [Data Structures and Algorithms by Aho, Hopcroft &  Ullman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201000237) states the following:

> If the list is a1, a2, ... , an, . . . For singly-linked lists, it is
> convenient to use a definition of position that is somewhat
> different . . . Here, position i will be a pointer to the cell holding
> the pointer to ai for i = 2, 3 , ... , n.

There is absolutely no explanation as to why this representation of list position is "convenient".

Why not just have position i directly as the pointer to ai for i = 2, 3 , ... , n?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Arrays allow access by an index, so it is convenient to manipulate indices; Linked-lists allow access by a pointer, so it is convenient to manipulate pointers.

Comment: @Stef Why not just define position i directly as the pointer to ai for i = 2, 3 , ... , n instead of position i being a pointer to the cell holding the pointer to ai for i = 2, 3 , ... , n?